# I defined a function to Tokenize my text but calling the function generated an error as seen below, kindly asssist

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, stack-overflow, text-mining

```
def preprocess_text(text):
    tokenized_document = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer('[a-zA-Z0-9\']+')
    cleaned_tokens = [word.lower() for word in tokenized_document if word.lower() not in stop_words]
    stemmed_text = [nltk.stem.PorterStemmer().stem(word) for word in cleaned_tokens]
    return stemmed_text

data["Text"] = data["Text"].apply(preprocess_text)

data.head()
```

Error message:

> TypeError: 'RegexpTokenizer' object is not iterable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tokenized_document` object is an instance of `nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer`. You are trying to iterate over the values of `tokenized_document` (in the `for word in tokenized_document` expression) but the `nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer` doesn't support that usage. (That's what the `'RegexpTokenizer' object is not iterable` message is telling you.)

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is that you have not called the `tokenize` method, and haven't used the `text` parameter at all.

Fix: call `.tokenize(text)`:

```
    tokenized_document = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer('[a-zA-Z0-9\']+').tokenize(text)
```